# Writing To RTF File Using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm trying to write out an RTF file using NLog. We want to have one RTF file per day, not per session.

Currently, I'm trying to write out my RTF file's header information (most importantly the color table) using the `Header` attribute of a FileTarget. In my message `Template`, I put in the proper markers (ie `\par` and `\cr1`} depending on the log level and the color I want the logs to be. I then write out the closing bracket in the `Footer` attribute. You can see this in my code here:

```
        string rtf_logMessageLayout =
            "${when:when=(level==LogLevel.Trace):inner=\\cf5}" +
            "${when:when=(level==LogLevel.Debug):inner=\\cf4}" +
            "${when:when=(level==LogLevel.Info):inner=\\cf1}" +
            "${when:when=(level==LogLevel.Error):inner=\\cf3}" +
            "[${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:MM\\:ss}]" +
            "${message}" +
            //add a ': ' if there is an exception and if ': ' isn't already at the end of the message string
            @"${when:when=length('${exception}')>0 and not ends-with('${message}', ': '):inner=\: }" +
            "${exception:format=message}\\par";

        string rtf_logFileHeader =
            @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil Microsoft Sans Serif;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;\red240\green240\blue240;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green128\blue0;\red0\green0\blue0;}" +
            "===============================\\par\n" +
            "LOG FOR ${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\\:MM\\:ss}\\par\n" +
            "===============================\\par\n";

        string rtf_logFileFooter = "\\cf5///////////////////\\par\n" +
             "SESSION ENDED\\par\n" +
             "///////////////////\\par\\par\\par\n" +
             "}";

        _rtfLogFileTarget = new FileTarget()
        {
            Name = "RTFLogFile",
            Header = rtf_logFileHeader,
            Footer = rtf_logFileFooter,
            Layout = rtf_logMessageLayout,
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
            ArchiveFileName = Path.Combine(logsDirectoryPath, archiveDirectoryName, "CubbyLogFor_${#}.rtf"),
            ArchiveDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd",
            FileName = Path.Combine(logsDirectoryPath, "RTFLog_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.rtf"),
            KeepFileOpen = true,
            ConcurrentWrites = false,
            OpenFileCacheTimeout = 30,
            EnableArchiveFileCompression = true,
        };
        LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(_rtfLogFileTarget);
        _rtfLogFileRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, _rtfLogFileTarget);
        LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(_rtfLogFileRule);
```

This system works for a single write, and concurrent writes will still write data to the RTF file. But there are two problems.

1. First, the file can't be opened by an RTF renderer until after the first write completes because there is no closing curly brace in the file, so the RTF renderer sees the file as corrupt.
2. And second, because the closing curly brace is added after the first write, the RTF renderer thinks the file ends after the first write, so any data written after that won't be displayed to the user unless they open the RTF file using a plain text reader.

I've tried to find others working on writing out an RTF using NLog, but I've found nothing.

A workaround, and something we might go for instead, is just using the RichTextBox log's `SaveFile()` function to write out the contents of our `log_richTextBox` to a file. If possible, though, I would like to get this working with NLog.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to address this?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar issue about having NLog FileTarget to rewrite its Footer-Layout (closing curly brace) on every file-append: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1658#issuecomment-604589881

Answer (score 0):

For this case I think it's easier to write a custom target.

E.g.

```
public sealed class MyRtfTarget: TargetWithLayout 
{ 
    [RequiredParameter] 
    public layout FileName { get; set; }

    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
    { 
        string filename = this.FileName.Render(logEvent); 

        // write to your RTF file. 
    } 

}
```

And in start of your program (e.g. main),

```
Target.Register<MyRtfTarget>("MyRtfTarget");
```

See [NLog - How to write a custom target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target)